# How to click a link within a hidden div via capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am using capybara, rspec, and poltergeist in a Rails 4 application and am trying to click on the following link button via capybara.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="invoice_invoice_items_attributes_0__destroy" name="invoice[invoice_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false">
  <a class="btn btn-warning remove_fields existing" href="#">Remove Invoice Item</a>
</div>
```

If I have the following in rspec/capybara, it finds the hidden element:

```
find(:xpath, '//input[@id="invoice_invoice_items_attributes_0__destroy"]', visible: false)
```

If I try this, it doesn't find the link  element:

```
find(:xpath, '//input[@id="invoice_invoice_items_attributes_0__destroy"]/a', visible: false)
```

The end goal is to do this:

```
find(:xpath, '//input[@id="invoice_invoice_items_attributes_0__destroy"]/a', visible: false)
```

How do I get there?

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` tag isn't inside of the `input` field, so unless `form-group` div is hidden, you should be able to just do:

```
click_link 'Remove Invoice Item'
```

If `form-group` is hidden, then try:

```
find(".remove_fields", visible: false).click
```

Comment: Oh goodness, thanks how silly of me not to notice - this is coffee driven development at its finest :)